# Ruby gem cucumber SSL error and Gem sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, cucumber

I was trying to install cucumber gem for Ruby.
Although there were few topics somewhat related to this, I can't find exact question with exact answer. When on Windows I try to run the command `gem install cucumber` and the console returned:

> ERROR: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ -
>   SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B:
>   certificate verify failed
>   (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Then, I googled for a solution and found some suggestions to remove source in [here](https://rubygems.org). I ran `gem sources -r` and it has been removed.

But did that not only in cucumber. Now I'm even unable to add source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue a while back after moving to ruby 2.0.0

Follow the following steps to solve it

1)Visit the url http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem save the contents as a .pem file(Do not save it as a text file.Make sure the extension is .pem)

2)Copy the file to any path in your local eg: C:\ruby200\ca_cert.pem (in my case)

3)Now add an Environment variable with Variable SSL_CERT_FILE and value "C:\ruby200\ca_cert.pem"(without quotes)(path is in my case.Replace with appropriate path) (Environment variables can be added by navigating to Computer -> Advanced Settings -> Environment Variables)

4)Close all your command prompts and restart them.Things should work fine now

Comment: That helped! Thanks! However, can you tell me how trustworthy this certificate is ? where it is from?
Thanks!

Comment: This is the cert that mozilla uses for CA trusting.There is an issue in ruby where net/http libraries does not check for the validity of the certificate during TLS handshakes.The problem I think is due to a missing CA store.This cert from mozilla adds the signatures for mozilla to trust.

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs due to changes in rubygems.org infrastructure.

Please follow the link below:

https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

Hope it will help you.