# Cannot install cucumber

Tags: ruby, browser, automation, cucumber

I have installed Ruby by way of the command prompt. Verified that I had the most updated version. I am now trying to install cucumber. Right on the cucumber site, it says to simply use the prompt `gem install cucumber` to get it to install. Gem fails to make the call to cucumber with these result on the command prompt:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cucumber' (>= 0),
```

here is why:

```
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: You may want to add environmental data (e.g. OS, ruby version, etc.).

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39897695/3328921 I had answered for the same error and it solves it

Comment: thanks you for your response